# How to upgrade/downgrade PayPal subscriptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

We have a website with different membership levels (standard, silver, gold) for yearly and monthly subscriptions.

How might we upgrade/downgrade the PayPal subscriptions from monthly to yearly & Standard to Silver, etc.?

- We are developing our application in Java
- We are dealing with the PayPal ipn message.

I have gone through the Paypal documentation- they mention modifying variables but I do not know how to do that?

Comment: probably belongs in webapps.stackexchange

Comment: Are you working with Payments Standard, Payments Pro, Express Checkout standalone, or what?

Comment: I am working with PayPal Payments Standard